# Change attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, attributes

I've got a selection/dropdown with ID `#pa_buy-sell[]`. What I want to do is if the value is *"buy"* I want to change the attribute `data-required="yes"` to `data-required="no"` from a input field with class `wpuf__regular_price_657`. I also want to hide the span with class `required`. The code has to work in WordPress.

I'm quite new in this, so I'm not sure what's the right code. But I thought something like this could be a good starting point:

```
$('#pa_buy-sell[]').change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'buy'){ 
      //something need to happen here
   }
});
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: When you want to change?

Comment: If the option "buy" has been selected

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct until now. You have to replace the comment with the following lines:

```
$('.wpuf__regular_price_657').data('required','no');
$('span.required').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the attribute to yes or no. you can use this:

```
$(".wpuf__regular_price_657").attr("data-required","no");
```

or you can use disabled as true or false, if you dont want to take input as

```
$(".wpuf__regular_price_657").attr("disabled", true);
```

and for hiding the particular span:

```
$("span.required").hide();
```

This will work fine in wordpress too

Hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Please check with "==="  which confirms Strong type checking (type and value) comparison and also refer the code for hiding the div with class required.

```
<script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $('.pa_buy-sell.wpuf_pa_buy-sell_657').change(function(){
       if($(this).val() === "buy"){ 
          $(".wpuf__regular_price_657").attr("data-required","no");
          $("span.required").hide();
       }
    });
    </script>
```